# Positioning a tooltip absolutely over relative text

Tags: html, css

I've got some text contained within a template that I'm attempting to add a tooltip to using this code:

```
<a  class="tooltip" href="#">Text<span>Tooltip pop-up text</span></a>  

<style type="text/css">

.tooltip {  border-bottom: 1px dotted #000000;  color: #000000; outline: none;  cursor: help; text-decoration: none;  position: relative;  }    

.tooltip span {  margin-left: -999em;  position: absolute;  }    

.tooltip:hover span {  font-family: Calibri, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;  position: absolute;  left: 1em;  top: 2em;  z-index: 99;  margin-left: 0;  width: 250%;  }   

 </style>
```

However, the issue I'm having is that I can't keep the text positioned relatively while also achieving absolute position on the tooltip (it expands but within the template div).

Positioning the .tooltip absolutely with the .tooltip span relatively achieves the desired effect on the popup itself, but obviously loses the link's positioning within in block of text.

Does anyone know a solution?

Thanks

Comment: This is one of the most unclear questions i've ever seen in this community o.O

Comment: You want the tooltip centered? I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
a.tooltip { 
  color: #000000;
  outline: none; 
  cursor: help; 
  text-decoration: underline;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.tooltip > span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}

.tooltip span span {
  font-family: Calibri, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  z-index: 99;
  position: relative;
  top: 1em;
  left: -50%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: none;
}    

.tooltip:hover span span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a  class="tooltip" href="#">Text
  <span>
    <span>Tooltip pop-up text</span>
  </span>
</a>
```